# tikz-pgf linear regression - start from specific points

Tags: pgfplots, plot

```
How to start linear regression from (0,1)?
    with this resultat 

t        x
0         1
0.01634   1.2822232
0.04902   1.9517734
0.081699  2.5069444
0.163399  4.0196319
0.245098  5.4139861
0.326797  6.4559171 



\documentclass{standalone}   
 % Required package

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
    
    \begin{document}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin = 0, xmax = 0.5,
                ymin = 0, ymax = 11,
                width = \textwidth,
                height = 0.75\textwidth,
                xtick distance = 0.1,
                ytick distance = 1,
                grid = both,
                minor tick num = 1,
                major grid style = {lightgray},
                minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
                xlabel = {Time ($t$)},
                ylabel = {Position ($x$)},
                legend cell align = {left},
                legend pos = north west
                ]
                
                % Plot data
                \addplot[
                teal, 
                only marks
                ] table[x = t, y = x] {result.dat};
                
                % Linear regression
                \addplot[
                thick,
                orange,
                ] table[
                x = t,
                y = {create col/linear regression={y=x}}
                ] {result.dat};
                
                % Add legend
                \addlegendentry{Data}
                \addlegendentry{
                    Linear regression: $ x =
                    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
                    \cdot t
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$
                };
                
            \end{axis}
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate the regression line for a specific x-range? If so you can try adding a new plot `\addplot [samples at={0,0.5}] {\pgfplotstableregressionb + x * \pgfplotstableregressiona};` after the one calculating the regression, and using `draw=none,forget plot` instead of `thick, orange`. The numbers in `samples at` define the x-values to calculate the function for.

Comment: Thanks, Torbjørn T, no it's not, I need the regression line to start at (0,1).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. The regression line doesn't pass through (0,1), so what line do you want to draw? A line that is parallel to the regression line, shifted down? Or do you want the line produced by your code, but moving only the start point down to (0,1), leaving the end point as is? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks, Torbjørn T,  yes i want the line produced by my code, but moving only the start point down to (0,1)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, forgot about this for a while.

---

This seems a bit weird, but for a one off you can do

```
 \addplot[thick, black] coordinates {
      (0,1)
      (0.326797, \pgfplotstableregressionb + 0.326797 * \pgfplotstableregressiona)
       };
```

after the `\addplot` where the regression line is calculated. To not draw the actual regression line use only `draw=none, forget plot` in the options for that plot.

In the code below I changed the legend entry, because the line you're drawing isn't actually the linear regression.

```
\documentclass{standalone}   
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfplotstableread{
t        x
0         1
0.01634   1.2822232
0.04902   1.9517734
0.081699  2.5069444
0.163399  4.0196319
0.245098  5.4139861
0.326797  6.4559171 
}\datatable    
    \begin{document}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin = 0, xmax = 0.5,
                ymin = 0, ymax = 11,
                width = \textwidth,
                height = 0.75\textwidth,
                xtick distance = 0.1,
                ytick distance = 1,
                grid = both,
                minor tick num = 1,
                major grid style = {lightgray},
                minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
                xlabel = {Time ($t$)},
                ylabel = {Position ($x$)},
                legend cell align = {left},
                legend pos = north west
                ]
                
                % Plot data
                \addplot[
                teal, 
                only marks
                ] table[x = t, y = x] {\datatable};
                
                % Linear regression
                \addplot[
                draw=none, forget plot
                ] table[
                x = t,
                y = {create col/linear regression={y=x}}
                ] {\datatable};
 
                 \addplot[thick, black] coordinates {
                   (0,1)
                   (0.326797, \pgfplotstableregressionb + 0.326797 * \pgfplotstableregressiona)};
 
                % Add legend
                \addlegendentry{Data}
                \addlegendentry{
                    Linear fit
                };
                
            \end{axis}
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{document}
```

[image]